# Number of ways to forming a committee of 3 persons from 3 couples such that a married couple does not serve on committee.

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve this problem using two different approaches and I am getting different answers. I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

One of answering this question is considering in how many ways we can select 3 couples out of 3 couples ($^3C_3$) and then multiplying by it with number of ways one person can be chosen from each of the three selected couples ($2^3$). So, the answer is $^3C_3 \times 2^3 = 8$.

The second way of solving this problem is to find the total number of ways a committee of 3 can be formed from 6 persons ($^6C_3$) and then subtracting from it the number of ways a couple serves in the committee which is ($^3C_1$). So, the answer is $^6C_3 - ^3C_1 = 17$.

Comment: There is problem with second approach. I am incorrectly calculating the number of ways in which a couple serves in the committee. Total number of ways in which 3 persons can be selected from 6 persons is $^6C_3 = 20$. Since we are making a committee of 3 persons, we can fill two positions from persons from same couple and we still have one extra seat to fill. Number of ways in which we can select a couple is 3 and there will be 4 ways of filling the third seat. So, the number of ways in which a couples serves in the committee is $3 \times 4 = 12$ , not $^3C_1$ as stated in the question. Thanks

Comment: $2^3$, or $20-12$, correct.

Comment: Since you solved the problem, I suggest that you answer your own question so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with second approach. I am incorrectly calculating the number of ways in which a couple serves in the committee. Total number of ways in which 3 persons can be selected from 6 persons is $^6C_3=20$. Since we are making a committee of 3 persons, we can fill two positions from persons from same couple and we still have one extra seat to fill. Number of ways in which we can select a couple is 3 and there will be 4 ways of filling the third seat. So, the number of ways in which a couples serves in the committee is $3×4=12$, not $^3C_1$
as stated in the question.